# Upgrading ATI Catalyst drivers fails

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I'm trying to upgrade my ATI HD 5770 graphics card drivers, as they keep crashing, but the upgrade keeps failing half way through.

I have tried the full driver package and the drivers-only package.

10-5_vista64_win7_64_dd_ccc_enu.exe
10-5_vista64_win7_64_dd.exe

I'm on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit.

How can I upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have the same problem I had. Take a look at this solution: [CATALYST install manager has stopped working.](http://insomniacgeek.com/blog/catalyst-install-manager-has-stopped-working/)
In a (rather big) nutshell:

1. Start the Task Manager and kill all processes that has the name of ATI*
2. Go to Control Panel – Device Manager and expand the Display adapters node. Right click the RADEON* item and select Uninstall. Be sure to select the “Delete the driver software for this device”.
3. Uninstall all ATI drivers and Control Center entries in the Control Panel –> Program and features.
4. Install the Microsoft Installer Cleanup Utility. After the software is installed, start it from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer Clean Up\msicuu.exe. 
   Find and select all entries that has the name of “ATI” and “Catalyst Control Center” and select Remove.
5. Install the CCleaner utility. Start it and clear any entries that has the name of “ATI” or “Catalyst Control Center”.
6. Open a Command Prompt as an Administrator. Change directory to C:\Windows and delete all ATI*.dll

   Del ati*.cll /s
7. Start Regedit, find all things named “ATI” and delete those entries.
8. Reboot.
9. Execute your downloaded ATI drivers/Control Center package. When the first dialog appears, click Cancel.
10. Open a Command Prompt as an Administrator. Go to the location of where the files where extracted and find ATISETUP.EXE. (in my case C:\ATI\SUPPORT\8-12_vista64_dd_ccc_wdm_enu_72276\Driver\Bin64)
11. Start the ATISETUP.EXE software with the following arguments: >ATISetup.EXE –install –output SCREEN
12. Wait for it to finish and then reboot.

Comment: Thanks for this. My machine was very unstable before this fix.

Answer (score 0):

- Windows should ask if you want to find solutions for the problem when it fails, and it should come up with a KB article on VS 2005 c++ runtimes.   You can try following that or doing what I did.
- Specifically, I navigated to the "temporary" folder that setup creates and installed from the .inf there.  Alternatively you could tell windows to search for drivers in "this location" being the temporary setup directory.